# Unhandled routes in espresso

Tags: ruby

Unhandled routes in espresso don't seem to raise a 404, instead I see this in the browser `"max params accepted: 0; params given: 1"`. Is there a way to universally have it routed to an error handler instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more about params rather than routes.

"X params accepted, Y given" message are returned by a resolved action.

most likely you have something like:

```
def some_action
  # ...
end
```

and calling it like `/some_action/something`
when `:some_action` responds only to `/some_action/`

To handle these errors simply add a 404 error handler:

```
class App < E
  error 404 do |error|
    # render your styled error page
  end

  # actions
end
```